# Node Modules not publishing for Visual studio code extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have developed an extension for Visual Studio Code.
Its working fine on my computer.

```
"devDependencies": {
   "fs": "^0.0.2",
   "github": "^0.2.4",
   "node-github": "0.0.3",
   "open": "^0.0.5",
   "typescript": "^1.6.2",
   "vscode": "0.10.x"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "fs": "^0.0.2",
   "github": "^0.2.4",
   "node-github": "0.0.3",
   "open": "^0.0.5",
   "typescript": "^1.6.2",
   "vscode": "0.10.x"
 }
```

The problem is when I publish the extension online and download it. I don't get those npm modules in my computer causing my extension to crash.

How can I **add those modules while publish?**. **If** there is **no possibility** then **how do I read a file and post it on github without npm modules in a visual studio code extension.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change it to.

```
     "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.6.2",
    "vscode": "0.10.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "github": "^0.2.4",
    "node-github": "0.0.3",
    "open": "^0.0.5"
  }
```

then run `npm install` and then `vsce package` then it will added into that extension file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at some of the extensions in the gallery https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/#VSCode. Specifically, the "Get Started" on the right usually points to a GitHub repo where you look at how other people have solved this issue.

I didn't use any dependencies like that in my extension, but here's the first one that looked similar to what you want: https://github.com/ziyasal/vscode-open-in-github/blob/master/package.json